# Generating a triangular matrix on MatLab with loops

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a triangular matrix from a row vector using loops. I know there are built-in commands that makes this easy, but I am a beginner programmer and I want to test this out.

Here is what I've got so far.

> function [ a ] = Up( v )
>
> n = length(v);
>
> a = eye(n);
>
> j = 1;
>
> i = 1;
>
> while(i <= n)
>
> while(j <= n)
>
> a(i,j) = v(i, j);
>
> j = j +1;
>
> end
>
> a(i, i +1) = 0;
>
> i = i + 1;
>
> end

My problem is that it shows me the iterative steps, all I want is the final answer. Also, I can only generate the first row.

For instance, if I give you $v = (3, 8, 9)$, I want to be able to return

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 &8  &9 \\ 
 0&8  &9 \\ 
 0&0  &9 
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Change line `a(i,j) = v(i, j)` to `a(i,j) = v(i, j);`. The semicolon tells matlab to supress the result.

Comment: It prints out the iterative steps because you do not have a semicolon after `a(i,j) = v(i, j)`. The semicolon is used to suppress output.

Comment: @Daryl, I did that, but now it spits out nothing when I do "Up(v)"

Comment: @sidht That's because you never assign anything to the output argument, `Upp`.

Comment: Oh okay, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you are seeing the output because of the missing semicolon on the line `a(i,j) = v(i, j)`. You also will not get any return value as the variable `Upp` is not assigned.

Given the way that you are using the loops, it may be preferable to use [for](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) loops instead of while loops.

This would result in the following code:

```
function A = up(v)

n = length(v);         % length of vector

A = zeros(n);          % allocate memory

for j = 1:n            % only loop over all columns
    for i = 1:j        % only the top half
        A(i,j) = v(j); % copy the value from the vector to the matrix
    end
end
```

You could also rewrite the loop using array notation:

```
for j = 1:n          % only loop over all columns
    A(1:j,j) = v(j); % copy the value from the vector to the matrix
end
```

Finally, you could use the [repmat](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) and [triu](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/triu.html) commands to create the matrix instead of any loops.

```
A = repmat(v,n,1); % create a full matrix with each row as the vector
A = triu(A);       % only return the upper triangular portion
```

Any of these will produce the same result as you are looking for.

Comment: WHen it says 1:n, does this mean it includes $1 \leq j \leq n$ and not strict inequality?

Comment: Yes. For example, the notation `1:5` is equivalent to the array `[1,2,3,4,5]`.

Comment: Never seen this array notation before. Very interesting. In your second code, you are "manually" filling the entries, but in the first one you are filling through columns

Comment: @sidht Yes, often there are many different ways to achieve the same result. One I didn't include is the possibility to fill the columns by diagonal using the [diag](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) command.

Answer (score 2):

I'm glad that you realize that there are better ways to do this. Having said that, this is the closest I could stay to your original code and and accomplish the said task. I hope you find it helpful.

```
n = length(v);
Upp = zeros(n);

i = 1;
while(i <= n)
  j = i;
  while(j <= n)
    Upp(i,j) = v(1,j-i+1);
    j = j + 1;
  end
  i = i + 1;
end
```